# Is this :$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \ \frac{\tan(\frac{1}{n!})}{\arctan (n!)}$ convergent sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence, factorial

How do I evaluate this  sum :$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \ \frac{\tan(\frac{1}{n!})}{\arctan ({n!})}$$ if it is  convergent  ?.

**Note:** I think the limit of it's general term is $0$ as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim++(tan+(1%2Fn!)%2Farctan(%7Bn!)%7D)+,n%3D50) in WA.
and i will surprised if it is convergent

**Note:** I edited the question beacuse i meant $ arctan(n!)$  in the denominator

Comment: "I edited the question be(ca)use (I) meant arctan(n!) in the denominator" Thus you are able to apply the approaches explained in the two answers below to solve the new version of your question, right?

Comment: @Did, ok thanks for that may be the intesting thing for the new version is the closed form of it

Comment: Nevertheless, you may start with your "and i will surprised if it is convergent". This would have the huge advantage of adding some personal input to your question, something it is sorely lacking of at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\frac{\tan \frac1{n!}}{\arctan (n!)}=\frac{\tan \frac1{n!}}{\frac{\pi}2-\arctan \frac1{n!}}\sim \frac2{\pi} \cdot \frac1{n!}
$$ then by the *comparison test* the series $ \displaystyle \sum_{n\ge1}\frac{\tan \frac1{n!}}{\arctan n!}$ is *convergent*.

Comment: Thanks olivier for ur answer , i edited my question because i meant arct(n!) in denominator , sorry for my wrong meaning

Comment: @user51189 Ok, I've edited my answer appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

$\tan\dfrac1{n!}\sim_\infty\dfrac1{n!}$, $\; \arctan(n!)\sim_\infty\dfrac\pi2$, hence
$$u_n\sim_\infty\frac 2{\pi n!},$$
which converges (to $2\mathrm e/\pi$).